Managing NuGet packages for local NuGet repository
We have a large .NET Framework application consisting of 100+ solutions, each containing several csproj files (some solutions contains 30-40+ projects). It's a monolith application consisting of 100+ different services, which communicate between each other and are always deployed together. The solutions have a lot of dependencies between each other - we use AssemblyReferences to point to a project from another solution. To manage the complexity, we have a custom build tool that runs on developers' machines. This tool is responsible for building the solutions one by one in the correct order.
As we were using AssemblyReferences, we were facing a lot of issues, particularly with dependency management — when a DLL is referenced directly, its dependencies aren't always copied correctly and dependent NuGet packages were not restored at all. That's why a few weeks ago, we modified all csproj files to output a NuGet package to a local NuGet feed instead of a dll and we switched from AssemblyReferences to PackageReferences.
This is how we modified our csproj file for Lib1.csprj (we did the same for all other libraries):
<PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>Lib1</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <PackageOutputPath>C:\LocalNuGet</PackageOutputPath>
    <RestorePackagesPath>C:\RestoredPackages</RestorePackagesPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="ClearNuGetCache" AfterTargets="Build">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(RestorePackagesPath)\$(PackageId)" />
</Target>

The problem that we are currently facing is that after we create a new build for Lib1, MsBuild does not recognize that Lib1 NuGet package has been updated and does not restore this package in the other solutions where it is used:
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 10 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Notice that we are explicitly clearing the NuGet cache with <RemoveDir Directories="$(RestorePackagesPath)\$(PackageId)" />.
When we use direct AssemblyReference, MsBuild recognizes that Lib1.dll has been changed and rebuilds the projects that are using it:
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 7 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

How to fix this issue so MsBuild knows that after Lib1 NuGet package is missing from the cache folder, to restore it and to build the corresponding projects that rely on it?
What we want to achieve is <Reference Include="..\AnotherSolution\Lib1\bin\Debug\Lib1.dll" /> to copy all the dependent dlls and restore the dependent NuGet packages. Unfortunately MsBuild does not do this. It would be perfect if MsBuild supports something like <PackageReference Include="..\AnotherSolution\Lib1\bin\Debug\Lib1.nupkg" /> but it does not support this as well.

So you just always want every project to be using the most recent Nuget package?

That's somehow defeating NuGet ... If you have Lib1.0.6.24 and made changes, you probably want to push Lib1.0.6.25 and then upgrade the consumers in a concerted manner to catch regression bugs. In which case you could easily go back to 0.6.24 ... You can still reference with wildcards to make that process easier . Like referencing Lib1, Version 0.6.*

Overall I think you underestimated the impact of that change. Especially in a wider codebase as you mention it, there is a lot more to it than what you describe.  Do you build manually or do you have CI/CD and if so which one?

Yes, what we want to achieve is to have only one version in the local NuGet repository and this version always to be the latest one. The project is being very actively developed and most libraries are modified 5-6 and more time a day. That's why we want a local repository but not a private NuGet server.

But if you only ever use the latest version, what is the point of using Nuget over directly referencing the csproj files?

We cannot reference the csproj file directly because we have 100+ solutions with several csproj files in them (sometimes we have 30+ projects in a solution)

That doesn't answer my question, you can definitely reference the csproj files.

Wait - does that mean you want to cross-reference to projects between solutions? In that case you'll have to actually restructure the codebase to create packages.

@Fildor, yes - we have a lot references from one solution to another. That's why we have a custom build tool, which builds the solutions in specific order.

Hate to say but have to: You're doing it wrong. You would need to come up with packages that build a unit and have an API and version it. That's what you can safely reference ... and that is what nuget is trying to be the tool for. You don't target a library but a specific version of a specific library.

@DavidG, it's a large monolith app and we use a lot of references to another solutions. Each solution is responsible for some specific domain and adding a csproj from another solution will make it impossible to maintain.

@Fildor, I know that we are doing it wrong but this project has been developed for 15+ years. It's a large monolith with 100 different component/services and it will takes us years if we want to split them into microservices.

Nobody said microservices. But you cannot just replace dlls with nugets and keep on doing what you were doing and expect that to work. As I said: You'll probably need to restructure the codebase and yes, that's going to take years if it's "naturally grown" and messy. I know, management doesn't want to hear that - they never do. But it's do or die. You can only try to make it as painless as possible.

In fact, what we want to achieve is something like this. Till now we had
<Reference Include="..\AnotherSolution\Lib1\bin\Debug\Lib1.dll" />
but caused a lot of dependencies issues (dependent dlls and packages were not copied).
If would be perfect if we can use something like
<PackageReference Include="..\AnotherSolution\Lib1\bin\Debug\Lib1.nupkg" />
but unfortunately MsBuild does not support this.

Because it's nonsense. You need to push packages to a package repository. You can then reference them there. If they change, they need to bump their version to propagate those changes. That's how that works. Yes- that probably means your custom build tool will need major changes (or be replaced on the whole), too.

Why are you referencing DLLs and not projects, by the way?

@Fildor, is it possible to reference a csproj from another solution? I will research it now.

Yes. A Solution is just a wrapper for a collection of projects, basically. You could have Solution A with Projects 1,2 and 3 and Solution B with projects 1,2 and 4 for example. I wouldn't recommend it. But I've seen it done. and it has its use cases, I guess.

@Fildor, the point is that we do not want to include the csproj to another solution because the support will be very difficult. Each solution has specific responsibilities.
It would be perfect if we can use ProjectReference to point to another solutions without actually adding it to the project but I think that Visual studio supports ProjectReference only to csproj from the current solution.

OK. Now free your mind for a second and read your own comment. If each solution has its specific and clear cut responsibilities, then it shouldn't need inter-solution references. If on the other hand you have some shared piece of the codebase, then maybe it should be treated like if it was a 3rd Party Library. That means: Completely different code repository and producing a (NuGet) Package (with distinct versions) that the rest of the system can reference and consume.

That fact that you then can also do things like have "preview" versions and enforce full versions for production in your CI/CD makes this very much maintainable in the long run. But you will probably not be able to convert your complete codebase at once.

@Fildor, "If each solution has its specific and clear cut responsibilities, then it shouldn't need inter-solution references." is not exactly the same. Each solution which is a server (we have more than 100 servers) exposes interfaces and data types. When the servers are communicating with each other, they use these data types and contracts. That's why we have all these cross solution references.

Right, so you'll want to extract those shared interfaces and DTO definitions into their own packages that you then can reference.
